# Finch Hello World Error: Http not a member of com.twitter.finagle

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle

I'm trying to use the scala finch library to build an API.

I have the following simple code:

```
package example

import io.finch._
import com.twitter.finagle.Http

object HelloWorld extends App {

  val api: Endpoint[String] = get("hello") { Ok("Hello, World!") }

  Http.serve(":8080", api.toService)
}
```

And a build.sbt file that looks like this:

```
name := "hello-finch"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("example.HelloWorld")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.10.0"
)

// found here: https://github.com/finagle/finch/issues/604
addCompilerPlugin(
  "org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full
)
```

When I compile and run the code I get this error message:

```
object Http is not a member of package com.twitter.finagle
[error] import com.twitter.finagle.Http
[error]        ^
[error] /Users/jamesk/Code/hello_finch/hello-finch/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:8: wrong number of type arguments for io.finch.Endpoint, should be 2
[error]   val api: Endpoint[String] = get("hello") { Ok("Hello, World!") }
[error]            ^
[error] /Users/jamesk/Code/hello_finch/hello-finch/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:8: not found: value get
[error]   val api: Endpoint[String] = get("hello") { Ok("Hello, World!") }
[error]                               ^
[error] /Users/jamesk/Code/hello_finch/hello-finch/src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala:10: not found: value Http
[error]   Http.serve(":8080", api.toService)
[error]   ^
[error] four errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Aug 15, 2017 12:56:01 PM
```

At this point I'm running out of ideas, it looks like a good library but it's a pain getting it working. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your example to work with the last version of Finch: `"com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.15.1"` and also `Scala 2.12`

the build.sbt file:

```
name := "hello-finch"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

mainClass in (Compile, run) := Some("example.HelloWorld")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.finagle" %% "finch-core" % "0.15.1"
)
```

then, the `src/main/scala/example/HelloWorld.scala` file:

```
package example

import io.finch._
import com.twitter.finagle.Http
import com.twitter.util.Await

object HelloWorld extends App {
  val api: Endpoint[String] = get("hello") { Ok("Hello, World!") }
  Await.ready(Http.server.serve(":8080", api.toServiceAs[Text.Plain]))
}
```

Notice also that having `Await.ready()` is mandatory - your program would exit right away otherwise.

Comment: dont we need to add the dependency for com.twitter ?